# Expand Layout and insert some fields dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I want to develop one application in which there will be a button on the screen and after clicking on that button camera will open and it take a photo after that, the layout in which button is there expand and photo comes below to this button.

I show this thing in one application whose screen shoot:

[image]

Here after clicking on photo it capture photo and then this layout expand and photo comes just below like this :-

[image]
[image]

I want same thing in my application.

For this I tried some code which is:-

(Already some fields are there in my application in TableRow which is in TableLayout)

first I create one  tableRow1 (say) after that I create one TableLayout and then one TableRow2 for the button and one TableRow3 for Image. I insert button into tableRow2 and then this tableRow2 into TableLayout and then I insert TableLayout into tableRow1. After capturing photo I insert Image into TableRow3 and then I insert this tableRow3 into TableLayout.

But this code not working, this code also not give any error.

Code:

```
tableRow1 = new TableRow(this);
tableRow1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
tableRow2 = new TableRow(this);

tableLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tableRow2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

buttonPhoto = new Button(this);
buttonPhoto.setText("Photo");
buttonPhoto.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

tableRow2.addView(buttonPhoto);

tableLayout.addView(tableRow2, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

tableLayoutMain.addView(tableLayout, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));



buttonPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            method1();
        }
    });

public void method1(){

    tableRow3 = new TableRow(this);

    tableRow3.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    imageViewPhoto = new ImageView(this);
    imageViewPhoto.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 110));
    tableRow3.addView(imageViewTakePhoto);

    tableLayout.addView(tableRow3, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
}
```

By using this code I am even not able to see button on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the proper `LayoutParams` also for the views that you add to the `TableRows`:

```
tableRow1 = new TableRow(this);
tableRow1.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
tableRow2 = new TableRow(this);
buttonPhoto = new Button(this);
buttonPhoto.setText("Photo");
buttonPhoto.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tableRow2.addView(buttonLocationPhoto);
tableLayout.addView(tableRow2, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
buttonPhoto.setOnClickListener //...
```

and the method:

```
public void method1(){
    tableRow3 = new TableRow(this);
    imageViewPhoto = new ImageView(this);
    imageViewPhoto.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 110));
    tableRow3.addView(imageViewTakePhoto);
    tableLayout.addView(tableRow3, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
}
```

Also, in your question, I see that you speak of adding the `tabLelayout` to the `tableRow1` and then adding(if it isn't already in the layout) the `tableRow1` to the main table. In this case:

```
tableRow1.addView(tableLayout, new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
//add the tableRow1 to the main table?!?
```

However, in your code you don't this, instead you have this line:

```
tableLayoutMain.addView(tableLayout, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```